# A question about angles in the Euclidean plane

Tags: geometry

It has long been known that an arbitrary angle (in the Euclidean plane) cannot be trisected using only ruler and compass, but that this can be done using a mechanical linkage. Given any positive integer $n$ greater than 1, does there always exist a mechanical linkage (as defined by Kempe) that can divide an arbitrary angle (in the plane) into $n$ equal parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linkage by J.J. Sylvester called "A Lady's Fan" [here](http://www.takayaiwamoto.com/Greek_Math/Trisect/Linkage/Linkage_Tri.html) can readily be generalized to arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Many thanks for this information.